# Can you 'require' ruby file in irb session, automatically, on every command?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am currently editing a file, and I'm using irb to test the api:

```
> require './file.rb'
> o = Object.new
> o.method
```

I then want to be able to edit the file.rb, and be able to see changes immediately. Example: assume new_method did not exist when I first required file.rb:

```
> o.new_method
```

Which will return an error. Is there a sandbox/developer mode or a method whereby I can achieve the above without having to reload the file every time? Require will not work after the first require, regardless. I assume worst case I'd have to use load instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I usually create a simple function like this:

```
def reload
    load 'myscript.rb'
    # Load any other necessary files here ...
end
```

With that, a simple `reload` will re-import all of the scripts that I'm working on.  It's not automatic, but it's the closest thing that I've been able to come up with.

You may be able to override `method_missing` to call this function automatically when your object is invoked with a method that doesn't exist.  I've never tried it myself, though, so I can't give any specific advice.  It also wouldn't help if you're calling a method that already exists but has simply been modified.

In my own laziness, I've gone as far as mapping one of the programmable buttons on my mouse to the key sequence "reload<enter>".  When I'm using `irb`, all it takes is the twitch of a pinky finger to reload everything.  Consequently when I'm *not* using `irb`, I end up with the string "reload" inserted in documents unintentionally (but that's a different problem entirely).

Comment: As a note, Rails provides `reload!` that does essentially the same thing.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall we are talking about irb, not Rails.

Comment: @Zenph I know… that's why it was a "note", and reinforces that this is a somewhat common way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Btw, using `method_missing` is a clever but evil idea. Of course it doesn't solve the problem where a method changed.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall sorry. Thanks. If I hadn't known about Rails console reload! method I'd be a very happy chappy right now.

Comment: Is there not perhaps a more improved version of irb, or a wrapper, which offers this functionality? I like method_missing response, but like you say, won't work with modified methods.

Answer (score 9):

This won't run every command, but you can include a file on every IRb session. `~/.irbrc` is loaded each time you start an IRb session.

#### ~/.irbrc

```
require "~/somefile.rb"
```

#### ~/somefile.rb

```
puts "somefile loaded"
```

#### terminal

```
> irb
somefile loaded
irb(main):001:0>
```

`~/.irbrc` is loaded each time you start an irb session

Answer (score 1):

What about `require_dependency` from **ActiveSupport** library?

```
require 'active_support/dependencies' #load it at the beginning
require_dependency 'myscript.rb'
```

Then `require_dependency` should track the changes in `myscript` file and reload it.

Comment: I've tested it and unfortunately it didn't work, maybe someone else can make it work.